# How can I add multiple elements to a vector based on a condition?

Tags: r, list, vector, append

Here is what I am trying to accomplish. Say I have this vector

```
example <- c("a", "b", "N/A", "c", "d", "N/A", "e", "f")
```

What I am looking to do is for each "N/A", I need to add another one after it. My desired output is

```
c("a", "b", "N/A", 'N/A", "c", "d", "N/A", "N/A", "e", "f")
```

for a vector of any length.

I have tried

```
position <- which(example == "N/A")
for (i in 1:length(example)) {
    append(example, "N/A", after = position[i])
}
```

but it doesn't work. I think the "after" argument only accepts one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
> position <- which(example=="N/A")

> for(i in rev(position))
    example <- append(example, "N/A", after=i)

> example
 [1] "a"   "b"   "N/A" "N/A" "c"   "d"   "N/A" "N/A" "e"   "f"
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `purrr:map2`, `Map` or `mapply`:

```
> unlist(purrr::map2(example, (example == 'N/A') + 1, rep))
 [1] "a"   "b"   "N/A" "N/A" "c"   "d"   "N/A" "N/A" "e"   "f"
```